scss modules (file.module.scss) does supposrt webpack if yes then how because I am getting undefined styles and file not loading in prod
scss modules (file.module.scss) does supposrt webpack if yes then how because I am getting undefined styles and file not loading in prod
I tried webpack latest and style loader (for prod minicssexractplugin) , css loader , sass loader in webpack config but after build deploy to prod unable to load content error getting for file.module.scss file and in console undfined styles object in react project
expecting to work scss module file.module.scss with webpack
